# Does this laptop support 5GHz wifi band

Tags: ieee-802.11

Does this laptop support 5 GHz wifi band? I googled it and I am confused as it shows both 802.11b and 802.11a. 
If it supports 5 GHz, why am I not getting it in available wifi connections? 
I have already tried upgrading my wireless drivers.
[N.B. My router is configured. My HTC-M8 phone gets the 5 GHz band]

[image]

Comment: Host configuration questions are off-topic here, but the short answer to your question is yes.